# why does second subscribtion not receive any values when subscribing twice to observable in rx 2.3?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I have this barebones example not behaving as I expect based on the [documentation of rxjs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables). I would expect the subscriptions to both receive all values.

The docs mention:

> Two observers then subscribe to this sequence and print out its values. You will notice that **the sequence is reset** for each subscriber, in which the second subscription will restart the sequence from the first value.

```
let s1 = rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 11])

s1.subscribe(
    x => console.log(x), 
    x => console.log(x), 
    x => console.log('complete'))

s1.subscribe(
    x => console.log(x), 
    x => console.log(x), 
    x => console.log('complete'))
```

However the second subscription just logs 'complete'

As it turns out the example works as expected in rxjs 2.4, but not in 2.3. Does anyone know what changed? I cannot spot it in [the release notes](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/releases)

Here is a jsfiddle with 2.3.20: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o93sxsc0/)

and here is one with 2.4.1: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he53s1xp/)

Comment: Just sounds like a bug.  They are going through and optimizing the code and it sounds like they just broke it briefly.

Comment: updating rx fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

This not right behavior for a cold observable. An observable which created from an array is cold observable and cannot share subscription more than on one observer. For correct work you can transform your observable to a hot observable. You can look on this documentation http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/publish.html. In your case you could use something like this http://jsbin.com/mowaco/edit?js,console. Now both subscriptions working parallel.